# React Native Push Notifications not coming in the notification pane in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I am trying the push notification for the first time. I followed a tutorial. After running the code, I send a test push notification from Firebase. The notification is appearing in the console log but its not coming in the notification pane.

My code is as follows:

RemotePushNotification.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'
const RemotePushController = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token)
      },
      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('REMOTE NOTIFICATION ==>', notification)
        })
        // process the notification here
      },
      // Android only: GCM or FCM Sender ID
      senderID: '############',
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true
    })
  }, [])
  return null
}
export default RemotePushController
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.app3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@android:color/white"/>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the console log

```
 REMOTE NOTIFICATION ==> {"channelId": "fcm_fallback_notification_channel", "color": null, "data": {}, "finish": [Function finish], "foreground": true, "id": "1987265985", "message": "fwafwaawf", "priority": "high", "sound": null, "tag": "campaign_collapse_key_4557183047135736330", "title": "fawfaf", "userInteraction": false, "visibility": "private"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to create a channel management for android.
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#channel-management-android.

Go through above link you will get to know since few months back they have updated it

Add below line in I am trying the push notification for the first time. I followed a tutorial. After running the code, I send a test push notification from Firebase. The notification is appearing in the console log but its not coming in the notification pane.

My code is as follows: **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
  android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Hopefully you will receive notification